# handling .CSV when one of it's value may include a comma in the string

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I have a .csv that I need to convert to a coldfusion query.  I have used the cflib.org CSVtoQuery method which works fine... but...

If there is a 'cell' in the csv that includes a comma in the string, such as a list, the query row for that record gets messed up as it sees the comma in the string as a new value.

I have no control over how the data is going in, so I can't have it written or passed inside quotes or the like.

Does anyone know if there is a way to process a .csv (convert to a query or other workable struct) that may have commas in the values?

Comment: try `cfhttp` http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2011/9/28/CSV-File-Reading-using-cfhttp

Comment: Thanks Henry.. have already tried that, but without success.  Unfortuntely I am not getting isQuery(mycsv) returning a positive, and attempts to loop over the csv like a query fail. Thanks again Henry..

Comment: _"I can't have it written or passed inside quotes or the like."_ - you mean the file is not a valid CSV file?

Comment: What Peter said... if you have a CSV that has commas that are not inside string delimiters, then it's completely invalid and can't be safely processed.

Comment: It's in export from a third party tool. Yes, lookng like an invalid csv, but it is what it is and all I have to work with. thanks guys.

Comment: An interesting thing is that if I open the csv in excel, it places values correctly. Icahn save it a an .xls and process it fine using cfspreadsheet (but I'm not always able to do this manual step). So I guess if excel can do it, it must be doable... Maybe...

Comment: Assuming these values are quoted, did you try looking at Ben Nadel's site? I thought he had a udf that handled this. Possibly this one http://www.bennadel.com/blog/501-Parsing-CSV-Values-In-To-A-ColdFusion-Query.htm

Comment: Can cfspreadsheet handle the original file? If not, create a dummy file (containing a handful or rows with sensitive data removed) and we can see if it's possible to "de-corrupt" into actual CSV. :)

Comment: @Jason - I did not see a clear answer to the earlier questions about the format.  Are the values enclosed in quotes or not? If Excel can parse the file correctly, that suggests the values *are* enclosed in quotes and that the format *is* valid.  Can you clarify?

Comment: does it have a backslash or any other escape character ahead of the (non-delimiting) comma?

Comment: THanks all, appreciate the discussion on this.  I am kind of with Jason Dean on this, but a problem I have come across a couple of times in the past, so would be interesting to see if there is a way around it.  No, the value is not wrapped in double quotes.  The field causing the problem is an address field that can be populated by end user submission.  If someone puts a comma in their address it obviously flows through and causes the issue being discussed. It also makes sense to me that it isn't acheivable, but excels behaviour has me curious.  will play today and let you know what I find.

Comment: Oh.. if they are *not* in quotes then I agree with those that said invalid/impossible ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Whoever is making the CSV is not making it properly. No CSV parser can tell the difference between commas that separate and commas that don't if there is no way to tell the difference.

Whoever is making the file should choose a different delimiter.

Comment: Yep. You must have something that allows you to distinguish a field. There's actually an RFC for the CSV format - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 - which says "6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes."

Comment: True. Though he later said *"if I open the csv in excel, it places values correctly"*. That strongly suggests the values are enclosed in quotes. Otherwise, Excel would have had the same problem.

Comment: He also said in his original statement "I have no control over how the data is going in, so I can't have it written or passed inside quotes or the like."  I was answering based on that.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I have given this a good bash. But not to not to be.

Comment: @JasonDean - Sure, and that is what I would have answered too :) His later comments just raised some questions, because Excel should behave the same as any other parser. So maybe there was something more to the data than was not mentioned. But turns out that was probably a fluke and your initial answer was right on the money.