# Regex help required to process a csv file in Perl having a comma in the value itself

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I need a help on csv parsing when the value itself has a comma in it.
I already learnt from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056038/handling-csv-when-one-of-its-value-may-include-a-comma-in-the-string) that it is not possible to deal with.

However, I think, I have an idea which can implemented if a little help is provided to build the regex. Let's say my csv file is having below patterns as each of it value :

```
"109", "[53G]", "/a/unix/path/", "", "hi 'sir', good morning", "error -msg "wrong input" -line_num "3rd line" ", ""
```

When above line (or similar) is encountered, I want "hi 'sir', good morning" to be collected in a variable or so as is. But as you already know, the phrase/value is getting split with respect to the comma (,) in between 'sir' and 'good'.

I have written a code which is working on a simplified version of it given below :

```
"a", "b", "c, cd", "d"
```

The code that could match the above line is as follows :

```
if($line =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9],[\sa-zA-Z0-9]/) {
    print "It matched \n";
}
```

To further explain the idea and the pseudo code would be to :

1) Match a/all pattern(s) where the comma is not preceded or followed by a double quote
2) Then replace the comma by some phrase and collect the exact value within "" 
3) After collecting the cell value in a variable , replace the deliberately substituted phrase by the comma again and do the processing.

If somebody can help me with the regex for the real pattern I mentioned above which will check against all values around the comma except a double quote and do the replacement steps as above would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the `Text::CSV` module instead of a regexp?

Comment: @DovGrobgeld I need to check that whether it fits in my requirement or not as my main purpose is to convert a csv to JSON. I will get back to you on this.

Comment: I see that a negative character class [^"] around the comma might do my job in all cases.

Comment: The main problem here isn't the embedded commas but the embedded double-quotes as in the field `"error -msg "wrong input" -line_num "3rd line" "`

Comment: I would suggest using an existing parser such as Text::CSV_XS, but you don't have valid CSV! You have spaces after the commas, but that can be handled using `allow_whitespace => 1`. Your unescaped quotes (`"error -msg "wrong input" ..."`), on the other hand, can't be handled. You are therefore asking us to write a CSV-ish parser, but SO is not a code-writing service. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unable to obtain proper valid CSV data then this will probably work for you *most* of the time. But you need to be *very careful*, and suspect the parsing if you appear to be getting strange errors

```perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

my $s = q{"109", "[53G]", "/a/unix/path/", "", "hi 'sir', good morning", "error -msg "wrong input" -line_num "3rd line" ", ""};

my @fields = $s =~ / "(.*?)" (?: ,\s* (?=") | $ ) /gx;

print "«$_»\n" for @fields;
```

#### output

```
«109»
«[53G]»
«/a/unix/path/»
«»
«hi 'sir', good morning»
«error -msg "wrong input" -line_num "3rd line" »
«»
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste time trying to work this out with regexes. Just use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) (or, if you want a standard part of the Perl distribution, [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords)).

**Update:** I've just spotted that this isn't valid CSV. It's not the embedded commas that are the problem, but the embedded double quotes in fields like `"error -msg "wrong input" -line_num "3rd line" "`. You should go back to whoever supplies you with this data and aslk them to produce something that is valid CSV.

Comment: Yes, the problem lies in given file which I claim as csv. I got this file from somebody on which I have no control. However, thanks for your suggestion. I need to find some other way either by asking to  change the format of the file correctly or to take care of the problem at my end.

Comment: *which I claim as csv* Your claim is demonstrably incorrect. This is not a valid CSV file.